# What would you call a phobia of endlessly looping GIFs?

Tags: neologisms, phobias

When you share a GIF on WhatsApp, it runs in a loop three times and then stops.

When you share a GIF on Facebook Messenger, however, it runs in an endless loop.

The thought of a GIF running endlessly until the end of time makes me anxious, so I refrain from using them on Messenger.

What might a phobia of GIFs (or similar things) that run in an endless loop be called, assuming there isn't such a phobia already?

I was thinking maybe vrochophobia (meaning "fear of loops" - "vróchos" being the Greek word for "loop").

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess there are people now who are too young to remember [Hamsterdance](http://www.hamsterdance.org/hamsterdance/)...

Comment: And people who are too young to know that not all GIFs are animated.

Answer (score 1):

I like **ouroborophobia**, after the *ouroboros* -- a snake eating its own tail. It also takes a Greek root, but one that is more familiar in English.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I like the suggestion. It’s creative and the ouroboros symbol is rather fitting.

Comment: Just be sure not to confuse it with *boraboraphobia*, the fear of beautiful, Polynesian islands.